# Intellij: Possibility to search text for files with certain pattern

Tags: java, intellij-idea, grep

In Intellij (version 2019.2), is it possible to perform search for files (e.g. .java and .ts files) that meet the following requirements:

```
- Contains some text T1
- Also, does not contain some other text T2
```

For example, let T1 be `productId` and T2 be `ProcessedForProjectA`

Then the following Abc.java file should NOT be found:

```
package com.company.xyz;

/**
* ProcessedForProjectA
*/
class Abc {
   private Long productId;
}
```

and, on the other hand, if we remove that part of the comment, then the file should be found.

The idea is that we have a "complex" search filter for files.

The simple Find dialog (Ctrl - H) can't serve this purpose as it can only find some text for a given file mask (e.g. *something*.java, afaik)

Is there some technique we can use here ? I'm just listing Intellij and grep (I don't know much about it either, and also I'm mostly working on Windows) as something that I can think of.

Any suggestion would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you are using `grep`, `^(?!.[\s\S]*bad string).[\s\S]*good string.*$` should do what you're looking for. `findstr` on Windows doesn't support regexes of that complexity, so I think you will need to try another tool.

Answer (score 0):

Sure, IntelliJ supports regex patterns for their search mechanism. You must find one regex that matches your requirements and search the code with this pattern.